# React navigation auth flow using ternary operator throwing Typeerror

Tags: javascript, react-native, authentication, expo, react-navigation

I have a simple auth stack as follow

```
export default () => {
  const { state } = useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        {state.token ? <MainNavigator /> : <AuthNavigator />}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};
```

The initial state of token is defined as null in the AuthContext folder, code below. But when running the program i get the following error **TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_useContext.state')**

```
const authReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "error":
      return { ...state, errorMessage: action.payload };
    case "signin":
      return { errorMessage: "", token: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const tokencheck = (dispatch) => async () => {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
  if (token) {
    dispatch({ type: signin, payload: token });
    navigate("Home");
  } else {
    navigate("SignIn");
  }
};

const signup =
  (dispatch) =>
  async ({ username, password }) => {
    try {
      const response = await tracker({
        method: "post",
        url: "/user",
        data: qs.stringify({
          username: username,
          password: password,
        }),
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
        },
      });
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("token", response.data.email);
      // dispatch({ type: "signin", payload: response.data.access_token });
      navigate("SignIn");
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: "error",
        payload: "Something's not write, plz try again",
      });
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

const signin =
  (dispatch) =>
  async ({ username, password }) => {
    try {
      const response = await tracker({
        method: "post",
        url: "/login",
        data: qs.stringify({
          username: username,
          password: password,
        }),
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
        },
      });
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("token", response.data.access_token);
      dispatch({ type: "signin", payload: response.data.access_token });
      navigate("Home");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      dispatch({
        type: "error",
        payload: "Start debuggin",
      });
    }
  };

const signout = (dispatch) => {
  return () => {};
};

export const { Provider, Context } = creatingContext(
  authReducer,
  { signin, signout, signup, tokencheck },
  { token: null, errorMessage: "" }
);
```

The ternary logic is sound and I have defined the initial state then why is this error persisting.

Comment: isn't that same as state.token.

Comment: Still the error persist.

Comment: Add the code for `creatingContext()`

Answer (score 0):

While I was looking for state in token what i should look for is value.
The problem is simply solved with

```
{state.token != null : <nav/>?<auth/>}
```